# Getting current_user error when using Ryan Bates' CanCan authorization plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, cancan

The portion of the view that is applicable:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= project.name %></td>
        <td><%= project.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
        <% if can? :update, @project  %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
        <% end %>
        <% if can? :destroy, @project %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(designer)
      can :read, :all
  end

end
```

This is the error I get:

```
NameError in Projects#index
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<ProjectsController:0x000001016d62d8>
Extracted source (around line #18):

15:         <td><%= project.description %></td>
16:         <td><%= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
17:         
18:         <% if can? :update, @project %>
19:             <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
20:         <% end %>
21:
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had errors in my AuthLogic install. Or rather, not errors, but when I installed it I used current_designer (which was the main user I was concentrating on) rather than current_user.

It seems CanCan didn't like that.

So I am now in the process of re-doing all my user models. But so far, it seems to have fixed this issue.